# How can I one hot encode a list of strings with Keras?

Tags: python, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have a list:

```
code = ['<s>', 'are', 'defined', 'in', 'the', '"editable', 'parameters"', '\n', 'section.', '\n', 'A', 'larger', '`tsteps`', 'value', 'means', 'that', 'the', 'LSTM', 'will', 'need', 'more', 'memory', '\n', 'to', 'figure', 'out']
```

And I want to convert to one hot encoding. I tried:

```
to_categorical(code)
```

And I get an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<s>'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Per the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical#arguments), the argument for `to_categorical` needs to be a vector of integers, not strings

Comment: How can I convert those strings to integers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`keras` only supports one-hot-encoding for data that has already been integer-encoded. You can manually integer-encode your strings like so:

### Manual encoding

```py
# this integer encoding is purely based on position, you can do this in other ways
integer_mapping = {x: i for i,x in enumerate(code)}

vec = [integer_mapping[word] for word in code]
# vec is
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 16, 5, 6, 22, 8, 22, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

### Using scikit-learn

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

code = np.array(code)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
vec = label_encoder.fit_transform(code)

# array([ 2,  6,  7,  9, 19,  1, 16,  0, 17,  0,  3, 10,  5, 21, 11, 18, 19,
#         4, 22, 14, 13, 12,  0, 20,  8, 15])
```

You can now feed this into `keras.utils.to_categorical`:

```py
from keras.utils import to_categorical

to_categorical(vec)
```

Comment: This will create 2 encodings for duplicates, right?

Comment: if `vec` is the same, then yes, `to_categorical` will return the same values

Answer (score 8):

instead use

```
pandas.get_dummies(y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

## tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding

In TF 2.6.0, One Hot Encoding (OHE) or Multi Hot Encoding (MHE) can be implemented using [tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CategoryEncoding) , [tf.keras.layers.StringLookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StringLookup), and [tf.keras.layers.IntegerLookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/IntegerLookup).

I think this way is not plausible in TF 2.4.x so it must have been implemented after.

[image]

See [Classify structured data using Keras preprocessing layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers) for the actual implementation.

```
def get_category_encoding_layer(name, dataset, dtype, max_tokens=None):
  # Create a layer that turns strings into integer indices.
  if dtype == 'string':
    index = layers.StringLookup(max_tokens=max_tokens)
  # Otherwise, create a layer that turns integer values into integer indices.
  else:
    index = layers.IntegerLookup(max_tokens=max_tokens)

  # Prepare a `tf.data.Dataset` that only yields the feature.
  feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])

  # Learn the set of possible values and assign them a fixed integer index.
  index.adapt(feature_ds)

  # Encode the integer indices.
  encoder = layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=index.vocabulary_size())

  # Apply multi-hot encoding to the indices. The lambda function captures the
  # layer, so you can use them, or include them in the Keras Functional model later.
  return lambda feature: encoder(index(feature))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try converting it to a `numpy` array first:

`from numpy import array`

and then:

`to_categorical(array(code))`