# keras ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, numpy, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have tried using keras to one-hot encode my categorical variables from a string into a dummy variable. My dataset looks like this below:

```
    Region         Location           Price
    North Region   Green wood city    150
    West Region    Pebble hill        200
    North Region   Green wood city    160
    West Region    Pebble hill        250
    South Region   Astoria            220
```

I was converted my categorical features to an array using `numpy` and one-hot encode using `from keras.utils import to_categorical`. as shown below:

```
data = np.array(df1[['Region', 'Location']])
encoded = to_categorical(data)
```

However, i got the error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'North Region'.

I looked at the traceback error and this is what it said.

```
---> 43     y = np.array(y, dtype='int')
     44     input_shape = y.shape
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

> **Edit:**
>
> to_categorical keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None,
>   dtype='float32') **Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class
>   matrix.**
>
> E.g. for use with categorical_crossentropy.
>
> Arguments
>
> y: class vector to be converted into a matrix (integers from 0 to
>   num_classes). num_classes: total number of classes. dtype: The data
>   type expected by the input, as a string (float32, float64, int32...)
>   Returns

Comment: It need int data, you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227671/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-a-list-of-strings-with-keras/56227965

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I one hot encode a list of strings with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227671/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-a-list-of-strings-with-keras)

Comment: `to_categorical`, as stated in its document, only accepts integer array. Use [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Comment: got it! thanks @Chris for pointing it out. I missed it earlier when i was reading the keras document